# Лаги при использовании requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация, профилирование

Почему при использовании в коде ([пример](/a/703080/178988)) конструкции

```
requestAnimationFrame(function draw() {
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});
```

периодически возникают лаги по 300 мс, в которые Хром ничего не делает?

Обращаю внимание, что профайлер умеет показывать сборку мусора, но на этих участках она не отображается:

[image: профайлер]

[image: профайлер на области с лагом]

[image: всё помечено как idle]

[Скринвидео.](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2L34/RDiiqMLwr) Скринвидео записано независимо от таймлайнов (таймлайны делались на чистой странице, а не для сниппета). Скринвидео стоит скачать, а не смотреть онлайн, поскольку при онлайн-просмотре значительно ухудшается качество.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю все дело в движке v8. Более подробно есть описание [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation). Думаю необходимо вынести анимацию отдельно а функцию расчета координат отдельно, скорее всего пауза уйдет.

дополнение...
скорректированный пример:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function start(){
    var ball = document.querySelector('div');

    var x = 0, y = 0, t = performance.now();
    var g = 9.8 /* м/с^2 */ / 1000 / 1000 /* (мс/с)^2 */ * 2 /* px/м */;
    var v = 100 /* px/с */ / 1000 /* с/мс */;
    var a = Math.PI / 3 /* 60 deg */;
    var vx = v * Math.cos(a), vy = v * Math.sin(a);

requestAnimationFrame(function draw() {
  //var t1 = performance.now(), dt = t1 - t;
  var dt=10;
  x += vx * dt;
  y += (vy -= g * dt) * dt;
  //t = t1;

  if (y < 0) {
    y = 0;
  }
  ball.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";

  if (y > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  } 
  });
    }
    </script>
```

... вы привязали движение мяча к времени потока, это здорово, но есть один нюанс. Стабильность времени в потоке на уровне запущенной функции сильно зависит от того как укладывается во времени eventloop движка. Наглядно видно если вместо вашего параметра поставить статическое значение dt.
При замере времени timeline - смотрите eventlog. Скорость работы движка сильно зависит от нагрузки системы, и внешних процессов. Соответственно движок единицу времени при запуске timeline может отдавать по разному. Все тонкости тут сложно посчитать. Если просто вывести в консоль (будет тормозить) параметр dt - видно как он плавает..

Comment: Ни в ответе, ни по ссылке не увидел ответа...